# Print a page using Watin

Tags: c#, watin

I am using Watin to open some pages in browser(IE) and than print that page, 
I use  System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^(p)"); to send print command, it opens a print dialogue , now i want to click on "Print" button in dialogue box .
Hoe can i do this.. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
var diag = new PrintDialogHandler(PrintDialogHandler.ButtonsEnum.Print);
```

Maybe you have to fiddle around with it but the PrintDialogHandler is the answer for your problem.

Comment: This is the correct way to do things, but if you are struggling and need a quick solution, you could continue to use SendKeys and just send {ENTER}s or {TAB}s to get the same result (unless you need to change some options of course, then you have no choice but to use t3hn00bs answer +1).
Also, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx) or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx) might help.